# Postgres function raising error when calling from Python script but running fine in PgAdmin

Tags: python, postgresql, plpgsql, pg-trgm, gist-index

I have a postgres function called '**medrealize**()' inside which i am creating temp table and creating index for temp tables using below lines

```
CREATE INDEX SQLOPS_RefICD_ICD10_idx ON  t$SQLOPS_RefICD_ICD10 USING gist (code gist_trgm_ops );
CREATE INDEX regexes_idx ON  t$regexes  USING gist (icdregex  gist_trgm_ops );
```

When calling the function from pgadmin, the function runs without any issues.
But when calling the function from python using

```
cursor.execute("BEGIN")
cursor.execute("CALL medrealize();")
cursor.execute("COMMIT")
```

I am getting below error

```
operator class \"gist_trgm_ops\" does not exist for access method \"gist\"\
```

Any idea why its running fine when calling from PgAdmin and raising error when calling from Python?

Comment: You will need to show the actual procedure(it is not a function) `medrealize`. Also are you actually using `$` in table names? Are you sure you are connecting to the same database in the Python and pgAdmin cases. `gist_trgm_ops` comes from the `pg_trgm` extension so that extension would need to be installed in the database.

Answer (score 4):

Did you install the trigram index extension in your database ?

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
```

If not, try to add it inside your function .